# Not understanding the following recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$C_n$, the number of ways to parenthesize the product of n+1 num-bers,$x_0·x_1·x_2· ··· ·x_n$, to specify the order of multiplication.

"To develop a recurrence relation for $C_n$, we note that however we insert parentheses
in the product $x_0·x_1·x_2· ··· ·x_n$, one “·” operator remains outside all parentheses, namely,
the operator for the final multiplication to be performed. [For example, in ($x_0·(x_1·x_2))$·,
it is the final “·”, while in($x_0·x_1)·(x_2·x_3)$ it is the second “·”.] This final operator appears
between two of the n+1 numbers, say, $x_k$ and $x_{k+1}$. "

I understand the above, but from here on, I have no clue what is going on, and I was wondering if there was any other way to word this explanation to explain it because I don't understand it at all:

"There are $C_k$ $C_{n−k−1}$ ways to insert
parentheses to determine the order of the n+1 numbers to be multiplied when the final op-erator appears between $x_k$ and x$_{k+1}$, because there are $C_k$ ways to insert parentheses in the
product $x_0·x_1· ··· ·x_k$ to determine the order in which these k+1 numbers are to be multi-plied and $C_{n−k−1}$ ways to insert parentheses in the product $x_{k+1}·x_{k+2}· ··· ·x_n$ to determine the order in which these n−k numbers are to be multiplied."

I don't understand....at all. I think the part I don't get is the $C_{n−k−1}$ part, and I just don't know if maybe this explanation is not good or I simply just don't understand it but I really really really do not understand this

Answer (score 1):

Take any fully parenthesized product of $x_0,\ldots,x_n$ in that order; I’ll illustrate with an example for $n=6$,

$$\big((x_0\cdot x_1)\cdot(x_2\cdot x_3)\big)\cdot\big(x_4\cdot(x_5\cdot x_6)\big)\;.$$

There is always a unique ‘outermost’ multiplication, the one that would be performed last in evaluating the product; here it’s the one between $\big((x_0\cdot x_1)\cdot(x_2\cdot x_3)\big)$ and $\big(x_4\cdot(x_5\cdot x_6)\big)$. Here $4$ of the variables appear to the left of the outermost multiplication, and $3$ appear to the right.

There are other valid expressions are there that have the outermost multiplication between the first $4$ and the last $3$ variables; an example is

$$\Big(\big((x_0\cdot x_1)\cdot x_2\big)\cdot x_3\Big)\cdot\big((x_4\cdot x_5)\cdot x_6\big)\;.$$

How many are there altogether? The expression to the left of that multiplication must be itself a validly parenthesized product, as must the one to the right. There are $C_3$ valid expressions with $4$ variables, and there are $C_2$ with $3$ variables; any of the valid expressions with $4$ variables can be paired with any of the valid expression with $3$ variables, so there must be $C_3C_2$ possible valid expressions with $7$ variables that have $4$ variables to the left of the outermost multiplication and the other $3$ to the right.

The same analysis works for every possible placement of the outermost multiplication. Suppose that the outermost multiplication is between $x_k$ and $x_{k+1}$. Then there are $k+1$ variables to the left of it, $x_0,\ldots,x_k$, so they can be combined into a valid product in $C_k$ ways. The remaining variables are to the right of the outermost multiplication and must also form a valid product. There are $n-k$ of them, $x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n$, so they can be combined into a valid expression in $C_{(n-k)-1}=C_{n-k-1}$ ways. Each of the $C_k$ possible expressions on the left can be combined with any of the $C_{n-k-1}$ possible expressions on the right, so there are altogether $C_kC_{n-k-1}$ valid expressions that have the outermost multiplication between $x_k$ and $x_{k+1}$.

This holds for each possible value of $x$, and the possible values of $k$ are clearly $0,1,\ldots,n-1$, so the total number of valid products with $n+1$ variables must be

$$C_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}C_kC_{n-k-1}\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

The $k$ is an intermediate value, somewhere in the middle.  It's split up this way to handle a reasonable general case:  that you don't parenthesize the whole expression.  If it were possible to do this, then $C_k$ would be ill-defined because you could put as many sets of parentheses around a particular expression as you wanted.

So one multiplication is outside any parentheses, and that location is determined by the value $k$ where $0 \leq k < n$:

$$x_0 \times x_1 \times x_2 \times ... \times x_{k-1} \times x_k \times x_{k+1} \times ... \times x_n.$$

So there are $C_k$ ways to parenthesize the terms from $x_k$ all the way left, and $C_{n-(k+1)} = C_{n-k-1}$ ways to parenthesize the terms $x_{k+1}$ all the way right.  The total number of ways is the product of these two numbers.

Hope that helps.